# Google Maps Drawing Manager - How can I delete a marker?

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps Drawing Manager library to draw shapes and markers on the map.  I am using [this implementation](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r282/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html) that lets you delete shapes. However it does not let you delete a marker.  How can I delete a marker?

For shapes, it detects the completion of the shape event and uses that to create an event that lets you select the shape.  But this event doesn't trigger when you create a marker.

Where is the overlay of markers stored?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by removing the restriction on overlaytypes

```
if ((e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER)
```

And then I had to restrict two instances of setEditable to not execute for a shape that is a marker (as markers cannot be editable). I did this by testing if the shape was draggable -- as my markers are draggable.

Example:
    if (selectedShape.draggable !=true) {
    selectedShape.setEditable(false);
    }